# Two Multidimensional arrays, need to combine to echo out in order by date php

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array, array-merge

Im probably going about this the wrong way, here is what im trying to do:

I have 2 arrays, both from the Jira bug system, one is for comments, the other is for attachments, both are different objects when pulling from the API but i want to show both combined and print out the results so that there displayed in chronological order.

For example right now its:

```
comment 1 - 5th April
Comment 2 - 20th April
comment 3 - 9th June

attachment 1 - 5th April
attachment 2 - 20th April

I want to dislay that as:
comment 1 - 5th April
attachment 1 - 5th April
Comment 2 - 20th April
attachment 2 - 20th April
comment 3 - 9th June
```

Ok so here is my attachment array:

```
$attachments = $issue_json->fields->attachment;
        $result1 = array();

        foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
            {
            $result1[] = array
                (
                'attachment_date' => convert_time($attachment->created),
                'attachment_epoch' => convert_sql_time($attachment->created),
                'attachment_displayName' => $attachment->author->displayName,
                'attachment_filename' => $attachment->filename,
                'attachment_file_type' => $attachment->mimeType,
                'attachment_thumbnail' => $attachment->thumbnail,
                'attachment_url_link' => $attachment->content,
                );
            }
```

Now that results in the following:

```
Array 
( [0] => Array( 
    [attachment_date] => 13th Apr 12 07:10 
    [attachment_epoch] => 1334301000 
    [attachment_displayName] => XXX 
    [attachment_filename] => 1.txt
    [attachment_file_type] => text/plain 
    [attachment_thumbnail] =>
    [attachment_url_link] => https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/attachment/18605/1.txt 
    )  

  [1] => Array( 
    [attachment_date] => 13th Apr 12 07:10 
    [attachment_epoch] => 1334301000 
    [attachment_displayName] => xxx 
    [attachment_filename] => 2.txt 
    [attachment_file_type] => text/plain 
    [attachment_thumbnail] =>  
    [attachment_url_link] => https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/attachment/18606/2.txt 
    )
```

Now the comments:

```
$comments = $issue_json->fields->comment->comments;
        $result = array();

        foreach ($comments as $comment) 
            {
            $result[] = array
                (
                'comments_date' => convert_time($comment->updated),
                'comments_epoch' => convert_sql_time($comment->updated),
                'comments_displayName' => $comment->author->displayName,
                'comments_body' => $comment->body,
                );
            }
```

And here's an example of the output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array( 
    [comments_date] => 11th Apr 12 20:52
    [comments_epoch] => 1334177520
    [comments_displayName] => xxx
    [comments_body] => Cannot reproduce, but attempted a fix based on the log file. 
    )  

    [1] => Array( 
    [comments_date] => 13th Apr 12 07:09 
    [comments_epoch] => 1334300940 
    [comments_displayName] => xxx 
    [comments_body] => 1) tested on a bit older version it still happens with it 
    )
```

Now what i had planned to do was merge the 2 arrays but im not sure thats possible since they dont have matching variables.

Can i just merge it into 1 big thing and combine the ones i need to match it on which is the epoch date cause i want to sort by that, so merge them until i have something like this:

```
 $result1[] = array
                (
                'date' => convert_time($attachment->created),
                'epoch' => convert_sql_time($attachment->created),
                'displayName' => $attachment->author->displayName,
                'attachment_filename' => $attachment->filename,
                'attachment_file_type' => $attachment->mimeType,
                'attachment_thumbnail' => $attachment->thumbnail,
                'attachment_url_link' => $attachment->content,
                'comments_date' => convert_time($comment->updated),
                'comments_epoch' => convert_sql_time($comment->updated),
                'comments_displayName' => $comment->author->displayName,
                'comments_body' => $comment->body,
                );
```

So the first 3 will match since both arrays have that, all the others will have values either for attachment or comments but not both, then once i have 1 big array i can sort it by epoch and echo out the results in chronological order

Would that work and if so what merge command in php is best, array_merge or the recursive one? Im probably over complicating it, im new to php so im a bit stuck in whats the best direction to go with this

Answer (score 2):

Wow, i had tried a bunch of things previously that didnt work but i tried this and it worked perfectly. I was just messing around while waiting for an answer and didnt expect it to be that easy

I updated both arrays to use the common jira_epoch variable:

```
$comments = $issue_json->fields->comment->comments;
        $result = array();

        foreach ($comments as $comment) 
            {
            $result[] = array
                (
                'comments_date' => convert_time($comment->updated),
                'jira_epoch' => convert_sql_time($comment->updated),
                'comments_displayName' => $comment->author->displayName,
                'comments_body' => $comment->body,
                );
            }

        $attachments = $issue_json->fields->attachment;
        $result1 = array();

        foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
            {
            $result1[] = array
                (
                'attachment_date' => convert_time($attachment->created),
                'jira_epoch' => convert_sql_time($attachment->created),
                'attachment_displayName' => $attachment->author->displayName,
                'attachment_filename' => $attachment->filename,
                'attachment_file_type' => $attachment->mimeType,
                'attachment_thumbnail' => $attachment->thumbnail,
                'attachment_url_link' => $attachment->content,
                );
            }
```

Then i found some code and it seemed to work great

```
$test = array_merge($result,$result1);
            function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['jira_epoch'] - $b['jira_epoch'];
}

usort($test, 'sortByOrder');
```